# Get model id where(value==x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have what I have to imagine is a profoundly simple question but I haven't been able to find the answer after quite a bit of Googling.

Say I have a user and each `user has_one widget`.  Now the widget table is set up as follows:

```
mysql> show columns in widgets;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to look up the widget's id by using the user_id and store it as @id in my controller.

I've tried several variations of the following without success:

```
@widget=Widget.where(:user_id => current_user)
@id=@widget.id
```

I sort of feel embarrassed asking something this simple but I really couldn't find a straight answer.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Widget.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` returns a collection of all widgets belonging to user - it does not take in account the `has_one` association defined on model, because DB could contain other records for one reason or another.

What you need is the first matching record - `Widget.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first`. Or simply `current_user.widget`, to use the association.

Answer (score 2):

If you just one the current user's widget you can use the following:

```
@widget = current_user.widget
```

This will use the `has_one` relationship that you defined.

For a different user:

```
@widget = some_other_user.widget
```

You can use the normal ActiveRecord methods in case you jut have the user_id. In that case you can just save the query that gets the user:

```
@widget = Widget.where(user_id: some_user_id).first
```

In all the cases you have to be careful, because in both cases `@widget` can be `nil` when nothing is found in the database.

Comment: Why query differently for different user and not just `some_other_user.widget`?

Comment: true! Don't know what I was thinking... probably just wanted to show a different way of querying it... updated

Answer (score 1):

You are slight correct, but think this is the way:

```
@id = Widget.where(user_id: current_user.id).first.try(:id)
```

So you have to select a widget for specified `user_id`, then selects first value (if any), and returns `id` or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

In where query always gives array

```
@widget=Widget.where(:user_id => current_user).first
@widget.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use association between user and widget to find widget id, like this:

```
current_user.widget.try(:id)
```

try is required for nil value if the current user don't have any widget then current_user.widget will return nil.